# karma test-runner error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'gapi'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, google-api-js-client

> karma test-runner error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'gapi'

Trace for ng test

```
28 01 2021 14:50:25.878:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.2.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
28 01 2021 14:50:25.878:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Firefox with concurrency unlimited
28 01 2021 14:50:25.880:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: src/app/auth/AuthModule.ts:12:21 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'gapi'.

12 import GoogleUser = gapi.auth2.GoogleUser;
```

`AuthModule.ts` snippet (**resolves correctly when running the app and inside `webstorm`**)

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/gapi.auth2/index.d.ts" />
import GoogleUser = gapi.auth2.GoogleUser;
```

`package.json` snippet

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.52"
...
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add types like this in **tsconfig.spec.json**

[image]

Comment: and in tsconfig.app.json